# Resizing the Cordova WebView in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, cordova, webview

I'm having problems resizing the Cordova (4.0.1) webview frame while trying to build a Native Hybrid application.  I am relatively new to iOS development and really new to Cordova/PhoneGap.

I have followed all instructions on this page, http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/1-embed-webview/ios/, using the CocoaPods approach with the sample phone gap project.  I have searched and tried other methods that are syntactically different, but essentially the same.

I've created a custom view controller class "GolfViewController" that extends the CDVViewController class provided by Cordova.  This code for GolfViewController.swift is below:

```
import UIKit

class GolfViewController: CDVViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x,
                                self.view.bounds.origin.y + 50,
                                self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                self.view.bounds.size.height - 100)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);
 }
}
```

The content in the webview should load with some space at the top and bottom of the screen.  Which it actually does, for a split second, then something in the cordova javascript forces the webview to full screen.  If I comment out the wkwebview cordova plugin in cordova-plugins.js, the webview renders properly with the space at the top and bottom, but then of course none of the controls work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as all documented approaches I've tried, have failed.

*************  SOLVED *************

There is a cordova plugin called "cordova-plugin-statusbar", that when initialized resizes the webview frame to take full screen.  This only happens when you have

```
   <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```

defined in the config.xml for the webview.

It does not simply "overlay the status bar" as you might expect from the documentation.  Setting this parameter to true actually completely resizes the webview to go full screen and will override any other custom sizes you may have defined before this event fires.

If you either remove the plugin (not really needed for native hybrid apps anyway) or you disable the "StatusBarOverlaysWebView" preference, then the status bar plugin will not resize your webview and the size you define in "viewWillAppear" will be respected and not overridden.  This should be updated within the official phone gap documentation on embedding the web view.